# Merge Pandas DataFrame using apply() to only merge on partial match in two columns

Tags: python, pandas

I need to merge two pandas DataFrames but not only on exact column values, but also on approximate ones.

For example, I have these two DataFrames:

```
import pandas as pd
d = {'col1': ["a", "b", "c", "d"], 'col2': [3, 4, 66, 120]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)

    col1    col2
0   a       3
1   b       4
2   c       66
3   d       120

d2 = {'col1a': ["aa", "bb", "cc", "dd"], 'col2b': [3, 4, 67, 100]}
df2 = pd.DataFrame(data=d2)
    col1a   col2b
0   aa      3
1   bb      4
2   cc      67
3   dd      100
```

Now, if I simply join them on `col2` and `col2b` columns, I will only get two rows where the column values are exactly the same.

```
pd.merge(df, df2, how='inner', left_on='col2', right_on='col2b')
    col1    col2    col1a   col2b
0   a       3       aa      3
1   b       4       bb      4
```

Now, say for the simplicity of an example, I also want to merge column values based on the integer that is either +1 or -1 of the integer value from the left DataFrame. In our example in the left DataFrame the value `66` should be matched to `67` to the value from the right DataFrame in addition to the rows with values `3` and `4`:

```
        col1    col2    col1a   col2b
    0   a       3       aa      3
    1   b       4       bb      4
    2   c       66      cc      67
```

Not sure how to approach this problem, somehow would need to merge based on the approximated column values using `apply()`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is one way from `merge_asof`

```
pd.merge_asof(df,df2,left_on='col2',right_on='col2b',tolerance = 1,direction ='nearest').dropna()
Out[7]: 
  col1  col2 col1a  col2b
0    a     3    aa    3.0
1    b     4    bb    4.0
2    c    66    cc   67.0
```

Comment: Does this only work for integers? I actually need to merge based on coordinate values, so my idea was that I calculate the distance between coordinate points (one coming from one DF and other point from other DF) using apply() and then merge based on the distance in meters given a certain distance threshold.

Comment: @ivan_bilan check scipy.distance then